# R data frame format group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame in this format-

```
ABC 2
ABC 4
ABC 6
DEF 10
DEF 20
```

How can I get this to-

```
ABC 2 4 6
DEF 10 20
```

I tried the [`aggregate`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) function, but it needs functions like mean/sum as params. How can I just display the values directly in the row.

Comment: What if the column lengths are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=F, text="
ABC 2
ABC 4
ABC 6
DEF 10
DEF 20")
unstack(df, form=V2~V1)
# $ABC
# [1] 2 4 6
# 
# $DEF
# [1] 10 20
```

`unstack` produces a `list` in this case as the columns don't have the same length. In case of the same length:

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=F, text="
ABC 2
ABC 4
ABC 6
DEF 10
DEF 20
DEF 20")
t(unstack(df, form=V2~V1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# ABC    2    4    6
# DEF   10   20   20
```

Comment: What if the column lengths are the same?

Comment: @Harpreet Then `unstack` will return the transpose of what you want (i.e. ABC and DEF are column names). Using `t()` will reshape it to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what are the observations? Are they suppose to measure the same thing for each category?

You can't actually get a data frame exactly as you have posted, because the number of observations for each category is different. But you could do that if you add an "NA" to the "DEF".

Like this:

```
ABC  2  4  6
DEF 10 20 NA
```

If that is what you want, you could just use reshape2's `dcast`.

But you have to name the observations:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(obs =c(1:3, 1:2), 
                 categories = c(rep("ABC", 3), rep("DEF",2)), 
                 values=c(2,4,6,10,20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- dcast(df, categories~obs)

df2
#   categories  1  2  3
# 1        ABC  2  4  6
# 2        DEF 10 20 NA
```

Comment: +1 for the `dcast` alternative. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21248135/1270695) for a way to create the "obs" column "after-the-fact".

Answer (score 1):

To add to your alternatives:

This seems to be a basic "long to wide" reshape problem, but it is missing a "time" variable. It's easy to recreate one by using `ave`:

```
ave(as.character(df$V1), df$V1, FUN = seq_along)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2"
df$time <- ave(as.character(df$V1), df$V1, FUN = seq_along)
```

Once you have a "time" variable, using `reshape` is pretty straightforward:

```
reshape(df, idvar="V1", timevar="time", direction = "wide")
#    V1 V2.1 V2.2 V2.3
# 1 ABC    2    4    6
# 4 DEF   10   20   NA
```

If, instead, you wanted a `list`, there is no need for the time variable. Just use `split`:

```
split(df$V2, df$V1)
# $ABC
# [1] 2 4 6
# 
# $DEF
# [1] 10 20
#
```

---

Similarly, if your data were balanced, `split` plus `rbind` could get you what you need. Using the sample data from @lukeA:

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=F, text="
 ABC 2
 ABC 4
 ABC 6
 DEF 10
 DEF 20
 DEF 20")
do.call(rbind, split(df$V2, df$V1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# ABC    2    4    6
# DEF   10   20   20
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to obtain a sparse matrix? The two rows in your example have different lengths. Try a function producing a list:

```
mat<-cbind(
c("ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF"),
c(2,4,6,10,20)
)

count<-function(mat){
    values<-unique(mat[,1])
    outlist<-list()
    for(v in values){
        outlist[[v]]<-mat[mat[,1]==v,2]
    }
    return(outlist)
}
count(mat)
```

Which will give you this result:

```
$ABC
[1] "2" "4" "6"

$DEF
[1] "10" "20"
```